# When "who" is used in a sentence with two subjects which subject will it be referring to?

Tags: pronouns

When "who" is used in a sentence with two subjects which subject will it be referring to, for example:

> *Between the cosmopolitan liberal "Anywheres" and the "Somewheres" who*
> *are supposedly uniquely rooted.*

Here "who" refers to "somewheres", right, but what is the rule?

Comment: One rule sometimes used is that it refers to what’s closest to it. But recast, or repunctuate, to make it clear.

Comment: The sentence in full is "It has been most successfully popularised by David Goodhart’s pithy distinction between the cosmopolitan liberal “Anywheres” and the “Somewheres” who are supposedly uniquely rooted in a geographically-bounded communities". It is unclear what the antecedent is.

Comment: When I read it, I assume that *who* applies to both subjects. However, that's by no means what was intended.

Comment: @Jason Bassford, Why it will be referring to both the subject I mean contextually too in the text there are "liberals anywheres" means no restraint, and there is another "liberals somewhere" which has some foundation  and the text at end talks of geographical foundation so I guess who must refer to "Somewheres" can you think it over and if you think it is referring to both subjects then please provide reasoning too.

Comment: @Jason Bassford, its not foundation its boundation, sorry if you are reading this comment second

Comment: @AmanDubey Interpret it this way: *Between the cosmopolitan liberal "Anywheres" and the **cosmopolitan** "Somewheres" who are **both** supposedly uniquely rooted.*